# Identifying sentences in a paragraph in C#

Tags: c#, .net, nuget

I'm working a on POC which is intended to find sentences in a string input paragraph. Before I get started, I wanted to know whether I could use any existing C# libraries or nuget libraries for this purpose?

Comment: Perhaps you're looking for `String.Split()`? Otherwise you'll have to qualify the problem you are having and where you are stuck. (Also do note that "please find this library for me" questions are off-topic here)

Comment: @lc. - Thanks for your reply. '.' could be used as a general rule in getting sentences using String.split('.') on a paragraph. But, my doubt is whether 'Considering '.' only as a sentence delimiter is valid? Are there any other rules in getting sentences in a paragraph

Answer (score 2):

How about [this from the Stanford Natural Language Processing Group](https://sergey-tihon.github.io/Stanford.NLP.NET/)? Although this might be overkill as you can just string Split() from punctuation marks (period, question mark, exclamation point, interrobang, etc.) depending on what you need.

Comment: Thanks. I will look into it.